# Prevent alias to alias redefinition C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I want hide library implementation from user and provide public API with aliasing of implementation, to reduce code duplication. So if I have two logically different API structs, but they implementation is equal, implementation would be aliased as shown in code snippet.

```
// library implementation
namespace impl {
    struct A {};
}

// library public API
using A1 = impl::A;
using A2 = impl::A;

// library usage
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    using type = A1;
    // do some stuff
    using type = A2; // prevent this redefinition with reporting warning or error
    // do some more stuff
    return 0;
}
```

But it may lead to hidden logical errors if user decide to redefine alias to library public API as in code snippet, because it compiles just fine. So the question is:

Is it possible to prevent alias to alias redefinition if redefined aliases are referenced to the same types?

Comment: It's problematic since `type`, `A1`, `A2` and `impl::A` are all the same type, which means there's really no redefinition. Perhaps if you try to explain what your *original* problem you try to solve is, we might be able to help you with that instead? I.e. the reason *why* you want a solution like the one you show. [Very related reading about the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank you, for your comment. I've updated my question

Comment: You probably want to look up [namespace versioning](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2013.html).

Comment: Note also that `A2* X = (A1*)Y` is completely legal in your universe. One approach if you want to disguise types is to write a protected wrapper class that has public using declarations for the members it wants to publish.

Comment: An alias is not a different thing, it's a different name for the same thing. (In this case, thing == type). You cannot prohibit users from using whatever names they want for already existing things. If you need different things rather than different names, aliases won't help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you point to the same type, the compiler is totally fine with that, and I am afraid you cannot do anything against that.

From the `typedef` keyword which, in your case, is essentially equivalent to the `using` keyword:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef

> Typedef cannot be used to change the meaning of an existing type name
>   (including a typedef-name). Once declared, a typedef-name may only be
>   redeclared to refer to the same type again.

So, it is an error to re-declare a typedef-name with a different *type-id*. It does nothing to re-declare a typedef-name with the same *type-id*.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix might be inheritance:

```
struct A1 : public impl::A
{
  using A::A;
};
struct A2 : public impl::A
{
  using A::A;
};
```

This defines new types, but reuses the implementation. You could even use private inheritance but that will require more `using` declarations for other members.